# How does Lucene compute multifield score?

Tags: lucene, information-retrieval

Here's Lucene scoring equation:

score(q,d)   =  coord(q,d) · queryNorm(q)  ·  ∑  ( tf(t in d)  · idf(t)2 · t.getBoost() · norm(t,d)  )

What about multifield scoring?

Does the score gets directly summed or averaged or..?

Answer (score 3):

You can read the details of scoring in [Similarity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html) class.  In this equation, the parameters are referred in reference to Document when they actually mean Field. So, Term Frequency is the frequency of the term in given field in the document. This automatically takes care of the queries on multiple fields.

KenE's answer above is incorrect. (There is no MAX operator in the equation.) The score for each query on a field adds up to the final score. For the query (name:bill OR gender:male) the result is sum of score for (name:bill) and (gender:male). Typically, the documents which satisfy both these criteria will score higher (due to sum) and come up.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the operation.  If you are doing an OR as in (name:bill OR gender:male), it takes the max of the two.  If you are doing an AND, it will do a sum.

Answer (score 0):

Shashikant Kore is correct to say that scores for each field are summed. This, however, is only true before the contribution of the `queryNorm` and `coord` factors, meaning the final scores will not likely add up.

Each score is multiplied by the [`queryNorm`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html#formula_queryNorm) factor, which is calculated per query and hence differs for each of `(name:bill)`, `(gender:male)`, and `(name:bill OR gender:male)`. Nor is the `queryNorm` for the combined query merely the sum of the `queryNorm`s for the two single-term queries.  So the scores only sum if you divide each score by the `queryNorm` factor for that query.

The [`coord`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html#formula_coord) factor may also pay a part: the default scorer multiplies the score by the proportion of query terms that were matched.  So you can only rely on summation after accounting for `queryNorm` where all terms match (or `coord` is disabled).

You can see exactly how a score is calculated using the [`explain`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#explain%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20int%29) functionality, available in Solr through the `debugQuery=true` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Using lucene's default similarity score, I have used a boolean query and got the final formula as following: (sorry it is in `latex`)

```
score(q, d) = \sum_{f \in fields} \sum_{t \in query} idf(t, f) queryNorm(query) \times idf(t, f) tf(t, d, f) fieldNorm(f)
```

Comment: This is based on lucene 5_3_0